# Retrieving sub index on Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to query a firebase DB based on a subindex, my DB is as follows

```
"sites": {
    "MQioLLCxj0e5pDtZC03etFc7v573": {
        "es": {
            "-M6tcDKmhAQYxgNiD70j": {
                "bizEmail": "cfggg@gyu.po",
                "bizLogo": "****",
                "bizName": "hdhdhd",
                "bizPhoneNumber": 5556,
                "disabled": false,
                "hasRNT": "1",
                "hasRUT": "1",
                "images": ["*****"],
                "isValid": true,
                "key": "-M6tcDKmhAQYxgNiD70j",
                "ownerId": "MQioLLCxj0e5pDtZC03etFc7v573",
                "parent": "MQioLLCxj0e5pDtZC03etFc7v573",
                "rut": 585858,
                "siteName": "El elefante azul",
                "slogan": "probando ando"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I need to query the DB and retrieve based on the "-M6tcD..." index, but I don't have the "MQioLL..." index beforehand and don't want to basically retrieve the whole list and filter as this object my grow a lot, I remember reading something about this on a angularFire changelog but could not recall how to do it.

bottom line I only have the second element key, but not the first one, is there a way to have firebase retrieving that data or do I just have and issue with my db design?

Im using angularFire1 5.3.0 and angular 8

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you saying you want to query the *es* collection for documents that contain the field `bizName` that has a value of `Trotalo` (for example)? If not, what are you attempting to query for? What makes the highlighed document special - how do you know that's the document you want?

Comment: Hi, bottom line, I have the -M7Q key and need to retrieve the item inside the es, maybe I should check my db design?

Comment: When responding here on SO, add an @ symbol in front of the users name so they will be notified of the response. Also, please include structures as text in questions, not screen shots. That way are searchable and can be copied and pasted into an answer if necessary. To answer your question: If you know the path to what you want `/sites/MQ.../es/-M7...`, just read it in and access the field data. No need for a query at all since you can access the data directly. The the Firebase Guide [Read Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) - see Get a Document section.

Comment: @Jay thanks a lot for the suggestions,  I'll fix my question, the thing about the query is that I don't know the first key beforehand,so I'm guessing if it's just that my structure is wrong

Comment: I am not sure what you're saying. The above comment says you have the key, so that means you have the path as I mentioned previously. Can you clarify what you don't have specifically?

Comment: Hi @Jay, I just updated the question, the thing is that at query time I only have the second index, and there might be hundreds of first-level elements and I don't want to just make a for to run all first level, also I'm storing the key inside the 'key' element of the object; from this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-a-specified-child-key Im understanding that I can query on the inner key will give it a test

Comment: You're not going to be able to get a single node inside the es node when you don't know the top node MQioLLCx. This seems like a design issue to me. Maybe if you can explain what your data means and why it's structured in that way we can suggest better/alternative structure. Maybe provide some short sample data that shows a more clear picture of the structure and explain what the queries are for. In other words, as shown, you only have one node inside the es node. With that, you don't need the es parent node at all. More info will help clarify